# CSS - how not to scroll parts of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

i see some sites which partially scroll, for example page is divided to 2 column.main and left. the main is longer than left, when scrolling the page by ending the left it stop but main also scrolls.
how it could be?

Comment: I think you need to use `position: fixed`. Read more about it [here](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101).

Comment: You can do it with Parallax, here is a sample: http://codepen.io/amustill/pen/aoFIm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are several implementations of the "sticky sidebar" in popular web frameworks:

- [Bootstrap's Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)
- [Foundation's Magellan](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html)

This pattern is usually implemented by switching an element position from `static` to `fixed` when it reaches a scroll threshold.

Here's a great tutorial: http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/

Answer (score 2):

use `position:fixed;` this will make it fixed in one position and never scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:fixed`.

### Example of usage

We have two columns: left and right. They are divs. This will be our HTML.

```
<div id="left">
    Non-scrollable content
</div>
<div id="right">
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
</div>
```

Now we will style them.

```
div{
    /* Following properties are applied to both columns */
    display:inline-block;
    /* default for divs is display:block what makes it display one under another, while we want them to display one beside another */
    width:50%;
    /* each column now has the half-screen width */
    color:white;
    /* we set text color to white ... */
    font-size:30px;
    /* ... and its size to 30 pixels */
}
#left{
    /* These properties are for the left column */
    background-color:green;
    /* background of left column is now green */
    position:fixed;
    /*its position is fixed, non scrollable */
    height:100px;
    /* doesn't really matter, but I want its height to be 100 pixels */
}
#right{
    /* These properties are for the right column */
    background-color:red;
    /* background of right column is now red */
    position:absolute;
    /* we want it to be scrollable, so its position need to be absolute */
    right:0px;
    /* its indent from right side is now 0 pixels */
}
```

How will it look? [Let's see!](http://jsfiddle.net/3EQW5/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: In Your, the left is fixed until right ends scrolling and then right and left scroll both. but id want both to scroll and when left finished stops and com down while right is scrolling...